# In King of Tokyo, which turns does Monster Batteries' effect happen on?

Tags: king-of-tokyo

Monster Batteries states the following:

> When you purchase this put as many [Energy] as you want on it from your reserve. Match this from the bank. At the start of each turn take 2[Energy] off and add them to your reserve. When there are no [Energy] left discard this card.

Does this mean at the start of only your own turns or at the start of every player's turn?

Comment: When you have multiple questions and there's not really a common thread between them, you should post them as separate questions, so that people who know the answer to just one can still post answers for you.

Comment: Please edit this into multiple questions.

Answer (score 4):

**It's at the start of each turn, including opponent turns** (assuming the designers are consistent in their wording)**.**

We can use the [text on some other cards](https://github.com/maltize/KingOfTokyo-CardList/blob/master/KingOfTokyo_CardList%20-%20EN.csv) to work this out. First, we can look at cards that specify an action on the player's turn, which are very specific. This includes cards such as *Herbivore* and *Metamorph* (emphasis mine):

> **Herbivore:** Gain 1[Star] on *your turn* if you don't damage anyone.
>
> **Metamorph**: At the end of *your turn* you can discard any keep cards you have to receive the [Energy] they were purchased for.

We can then look at other cards that use the terminology of "each", which are abilities you would only use on an opponent's turn. Two such cards are *Super Jump* and *Psychic Probe* (emphasis mine):

> **Super Jump**: Once *each turn* you may spend 1[Energy] to negate 1 damage you are receiving.
>
> **Psychic Probe**: You can reroll a die of each other monster once *each turn*. If the reroll is [Heart] discard this card.

In the first case, you'd negate damage during an opponent's turn, and in the second you would choose to reroll a die on an opponent's turn. So the phrasing "each turn" in *Monster Batteries* indicates that it occurs at the beginning of each turn around the table, whether it is yours or not.

Comment: You know what? I think you might be right actually. I've deleted my post!